# Appending JS objects to the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm wondering if there's any way to append a javascript object to the DOM? I have an object prototype which goes like this:

```
function Weapon(damage, type, src) {
  this.damage = damage;
  this.type = type;
  this.src = src;
}
```

And an object:

```
var potion = new Weapon(24, 'Potion', 'glove.png');
```

And I'm trying to append it to the dom by saying:

```
let test = document.getElementById('test-tile');
test.append(potion.src);
```

Which just prints "glove.png" to the dom element I'm targeting. 
Is there any way that I can append it, and that way not being jquery's .attr or
.data?

Comment: You need to create the actual HTML element, presumably an `<img />` in this case, to append, not just the text URL.

Comment: @Observer The point of it is to have a few weapons that spawn randomly across the tile map, and each of them having attributes, for example strength, which the player will append to their damage when he steps on the tile containing that object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Can you assing attributes to the html elements created in javascript?

Comment: @RonyDKid HTML is a pretty simple way to structure a document. If you want to display something besides text you are going to need to either tweak some CSS or append a canvas or img tag.

Comment: Yes, but it's much easier to just provide the whole HTML string to `append()` instead. I'd suggest creating a function within your object that creates that HTML and appends it for you

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the actual HTML element, presumably an `<img />` in this case, to append, not just the text URL.

I'd suggest creating a function within your object that creates that HTML and appends it for you, something like this:

```js
function Weapon(damage, type, src) {
  this.damage = damage;
  this.type = type;
  this.src = src;
  this.display = function(containerSelector) {
    $(containerSelector).append('<img src="' + this.src + '" />');
  } 
}

var potion = new Weapon(24, 'Potion', 'glove.png');
potion.display('#test-tile');
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-tile"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an image `element` which you can then place on your DOM. Seeing as you have the `.png` file name accessible, this is relatively trivial:

```
let img = document.createElement('img');
let test = document.getElementById('test-tile');
img.src = potion.src;

test.append(img);
```

Comment: So basically, you can't append a whole object to an html element?

Comment: You can, but you have to set the image elements individually. When you append a raw object it'll infer the type as a string and append `[Object object]` to your tile most likely.

Answer (score 1):

You can append an image element pointing to the source .png file.  Like this:

```
test.append('<img src="' + potion.src + '"/'>)
```